# eyeball showing through skin

Tags: texturing, transparency

[image][image]

Got the problem that the election of the eyeball is showing through the skin, how should i fix it? im using cycle engine to render [![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: if you are using SSS on skin make sure your eye is not emitting light. if your nodes make rgb colors go more then 1 it will emit light. add a clamp node before your color socket in shader editor.

Comment: not using SSS on skin, what is clamp node?

Comment: Hi, please [edit] your question and images of the shader nodes for the skin and eyes. Please indicate the render engine that you are using as well, and include any information that you think might be helpful to users in providing an answer. Thanks.